# pygame sprite and draw method not working as expected

Tags: python, pygame

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am writing a game with Pygame and after creating all the classes and methods I need. When I run the game I see five alien characters of my game showing up from the left side of the screen joined together before I actually see what i wanted my code to display (aliens moving at random positions down the screen).

here is my code:

```
class Alien():
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.x = random.randrange(20,width - 20)
        self.y = random.randrange(-200, -20)
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 5)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("../images", image)).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move_down(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speed

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

its implementation

```
for i in range (20):
    aliens = Alien("alien.png")
    enemies.append(aliens)

done = False
while done == False:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(white)

    for i in range(len(enemies)):
        enemies[i].move_down()
        enemies[i].draw(screen)
        enemies[i].check_landed()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

note: I have removed some code for clarity.
result

[image: pygame sprite result]

Comment: Why do you want `self.y` to be negative? Topleft screen corners coordinates are (0, 0) and they are positive on the whole screen.

Comment: I want it so that it can generate my image outside the screen so that the user doesnt see the images as they are being generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the position of the aliens in the fields `self.x` and `self.y`, but to draw them, you actually don't use `self.x` and `self.y`, but `self.rect`.

You create `self.rect` by calling `self.image.get_rect()`, and when you call `get_rect()` on a `Surface`, the position of the `Rect` is always `(0, 0)`.

So the `x` coordinate is always `0`, hence they are all on the left side of the screen.

I suggest rewriting your code to:

```
class Alien():
    # pass the Surface to the instance instead of the filename
    # this way, you only load the image once, not once for each alien
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 5)
        self.image = image
        # since we're going to use a Rect of drawing, let's use the
        # same Rect to store the correct position of the alien
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(top=random.randrange(-200, -20), left=random.randrange(20,width - 20))

    def move_down(self):
        # the Rect class has a lot of handy functions like move_ip
        self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# load the image once. In more complex games, you usually
# want to abstract the loading/storing of images         
alienimage = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("../images", 'alien.png')).convert_alpha()
for _ in range (20):
    aliens = Alien(alienimage)
    enemies.append(aliens)

done = False
while done == False:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(white)

    # just use a "regular" for loop to loop through all enemies
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.move_down()
        enemy.draw(screen)
        enemy.check_landed()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

You could go further and use the `Sprite`- and `Group`-class to further generalize your code, but that's another topic.